# GORM checks constraints before invoking beforeInsert method

Tags: grails, grails-orm, aop

A strange behavior with `GORM` :

```
    public class Student {
        String fullname;
        String subscriptionIdentity;

       static constraints={

          subscriptionIdentity blank:false,nullable:true // mean that this field should have value in DB
      }

       def beforeInsert(){
         subscriptionIdentity="S"+System.nanoTime();
      }
    }
```

When i call :

```
def std=new Student(fullname:"Ahmed OMAR")
std.save();
```

It seems that GORM does not invoke  `beforeInsert` ( or it invoke it after checking the constraints )
Because i've got the following error message :

> Field error in object 'com.abdennour.Student' on field 'subscriptionIdentity': rejected value [null];

Answer (score 1):

This is because `.save()` calls validation to ensure that the instance is valid.

In your case you may want to use `beforeValidation` instead of `beforeInsert`. You can read more about `beforeValidation` in the [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping).